# Xamarin forms iOS app has stopped communicating with local WebAPI timeout exception

Tags: xamarin, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

My app on the iOS emulator stopped communicating with the local WebAPI suddenly.

I have a Xamarin App (only for iOS) which communicates with the database using APIs. I have built another Web API project to write needed APIs. All the functionality was working absolutely fine until it stopped working suddenly.

- I am using VS2019 for development, I have Macbook Pro with latest XCode on it.
- My API calls with Fiddlers are successful.
- On the iOS emulator's browser (on mac and on windows both places), I can browse the local web API site (which is on my local windows computer) without any issue.
- Any API calls from an app running on the emulator are throwing a timeout error.
- Earlier with API were working, I could actually debug my WebAPI code after calling it from emulator but now it breakpoint does not hit.
- I tried resetting emulator, Updating VS 2019, Xamarin, Xamarin Studio on Mac, XCode etc.

Here is the error:
[image]

Comment: Does your local WebAPI has been upgraded to use TLS 2.0 security feature ??? if yes then update iOS Build > Http Client Implementation > NSUrlSession ... let me know if this solves your issue

Comment: There is no change in API side. my app was working fine and suddenly it stopped.

Comment: I also checked the HttpClientImplementatoin setting in iOS, it is NSUrlSession.

Comment: Did you make any change before it stops working suddenly? I guess it may caused by the network? Try another network or another real device to see if it works.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT no I did not add any backend code. It was working till late night and next day morning it just stopped working for no reason!! 

Error:
Foundation.NSErrorException: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out."

Comment: Well,have no idea about what happened if you did not change anything. You can try to check the server log to find any anything useful.